# Allure timing and logging automatically for each method

Tags: allure

Each java method annotated by @Test call other methods, example:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
  Data data = getData();
  verifyData(data);
}
```

I would like to know how much time required for execution `getData` and `verifyData` methods. 
I can annotate them `@Step` annotation and needed information will be appeared in the report with indication how much was required to execute it. But is it possible to have timing automatically for every method without annotation them?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve that is create a custom aspect that will catch every method execution within a class/package.

An example of such aspect can be found at https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/master/allure-assertj/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/assertj/AllureAspectJ.java#L35-L58